# How to parse an array to a hash of arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, hashtable

I'm a beginner (a wet lab biologist, who has to fiddle a bit with bioinformatics for the first time in my life) and today I've got stuck on one problem: how to parse an array to a hash of arrays in perl?

This doesn't work:

```
@myhash{$key} = @mytable;
```

I've finally circumvented my problem with a for loop:

```
for(my $i=0;$i<=$#mytable;$i++){$myhash{$key}[$i]=$mytable[$i]};
```

Of course it works and it does what I need to be done, but it seems to me not a solution to my problem, but just a way to circumvent it... When something doesn't work I like to understand why...

Thank you very much for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Grinnz mentioned you can save a reference to an array, but any change on the array latter will be reflected in hash (it is same data).

For example if you reuse same array in the loop then data in hash will reflect last iteration of the loop.

In such case you will want a copy of array stored in the hash.

```
@{$hash{$key}} = @array;
```

[Programming Perl: Data strutures](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/prog/ch09_01.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to put an array as one value of a hash, you do this by taking a reference to the array, since references are scalars and the values of hashes must be scalars. This is done with the backslash operator.

```
$myhash{$key} = \@mytable;
```

The for loop you describe creates such a reference through autovivification, as `$myhash{$key}[0]` creates an array reference at `$myhash{$key}` in order to assign to its index. Also note that the difference between taking a reference and copying each value is that in the former case, changes to the array after the fact will also affect the values referenced via the hash value, and vice versa.

```
$mytable[5] = 42; # $myhash{$key}[5] is also changed
```